# Get value that been selected from radio button in java

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class RadioButtonTest extends JFrame {

private JTextField jtfAnswer = new JTextField(10);
private JRadioButton jrbMale = new JRadioButton("Male");
private JRadioButton jrbFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
private JButton jbSubmit = new JButton("Submit");

public RadioButtonTest(){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(jrbMale);
    group.add(jrbFemale);

    add(new Label("Select gender:"));
    add(jrbMale);
    add(jrbFemale);
    add(jtfAnswer);
    add(jbSubmit);

    setTitle("Radio Button");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(200, 200);
    setSize(150, 150);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RadioButtonTest();
}
}
```

I know should add an `actionlistener` to obtain the selected values , but what is the content I should code in the `actionlistener` ?

Comment: @javaBeginner i think he wonna know how to get the selected radio button. Is this @Adriel??

Comment: Yes, example if i selected Male, and the TextField that should display "Male".

Comment: See this basic example on:

http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2009/01/get-selected-jradiobutton.html

Answer (score 4):

> I know should add an `actionlistener` to obtain the selected values ,
>   but what is the content I should code in the `actionlistener`?

Inside your `ActionListener` you can ask who's the source of the action event and then set the text field's text as needed:

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JRadioButton){
            JRadioButton radioButton = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
            if(radioButton.isSelected()){
                jtfAnswer.setText(radioButton.getText());
            }
        }
    }
};

jrbMale.addActionListener(actionListener);
jrbFemale.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

**Note** suggested reading [EventObject.getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `addActionListener()` on the item you want to listen to, in this case it looks like you want to call it on your submit button.  The action listener that you pass as a parameter then has the code that you want to execute.   Check out the tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

For each form item you will have to look in the API to understand what method to call to get the correct value.  For example: `getText()` or `isSelected()`.

Answer (score 0):

create your own action listner like this:

```
class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener{

    private JTextField textField;
    private JRadioButton btn;
    public CustomActionListener( JRadioButton btn, JTextField field){
        this.btn = btn;
        this.textField = field;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        this.textField.setText( this.btn.getText() );

    }

}
```

And then add it to your radio buttons:

```
jrbMale.addActionListener( new CustomActionListener( jrbMale, jtfAnswer ) );
jrbFemale.addActionListener( new CustomActionListener( jrbFemale, jtfAnswer ) );
```